# "Installing Docker: FAILED" Error on setup with Meteor-Up and Debian 7 wheezy

Tags: meteor, docker, meteor-up, ovh

I just buy a new VPS (from [OVH - VPS SSD 1](https://www.ovh.com/ca/en/vps/vps-ssd.xml) - Debian 7 Wheezy 64bit) and I try to deploy on prod my Meteor project using [Meteor-Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) (more exactly the [mupx version](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx)).

When I try to setup `mupx setup` I got some error for installing Docker. 
I tried to install manually docker on the server, and on my local computer. I also tried to launch the setup command with sudo, but nothing better..

Any idea ?

```
Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
[158.69.210.254] - Installing Docker
[158.69.210.254] x Installing Docker: FAILED

        -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
        opportunity to cancel the
        installation.

        If you installed the current Docker package using this script and are using it
        again to update Docker, you can safely ignore this message.

        You may press Ctrl+C now to abort this script.
        + sleep 20
        + sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D || apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
        gpg: requesting key 2C52609D from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
        gpg: key 2C52609D: "Docker Release Tool (releasedocker) <docker@docker.com>" not changed
        gpg: Total number processed: 1
        gpg:              unchanged: 1
        + sh -c mkdir -p /etc/apt/sources.list.d
        + dpkg --print-architecture
        + sh -c echo deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-wheezy main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
        + sh -c sleep 3; apt-get update; apt-get install -y -q docker-engine
        E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
        -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
        an-wheezy/main Translation-en_GB
        Ign https://apt.dockerproject.org debian-wheezy/main Translation-en
        Reading package lists...
        Reading package lists...
        Building dependency tree...
        Reading state information...
        Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
        requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
        distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
        or been moved out of Incoming.
        The following information may help to resolve the situation:

        The following packages have unmet dependencies:
         docker-engine : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but it is not installable
                         Recommends: aufs-tools but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: cgroupfs-mount but it is not installable or
                                     cgroup-lite but it is not installable
                         Recommends: git but it is not going to be installed
                         Recommends: yubico-piv-tool (>= 1.1.0~) but it is not installable
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because Docker version didn't work on Debian 7, but only Debian 8. 
Si just have to reinstall VPS using OVH manager and all work fine !